# Is there any major difference between SSIS 2012 and SSIS 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have not seen the SQL Server 2014,just wondering is there any difference in SSIS 2012 and SSIS 2012?Any new components introduced?Any new tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the MSDN article [What's New (Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522534%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), no changes have been introduced in SSIS:

> SQL Server 2014 Integration Services is unchanged from the previous release.

Comment: Let me know ,have you used the product?

Comment: No, I have only checked the documentation, so feel free to unaccept my answer and wait for one from someone who have actually used SSIS 2014.

Comment: I have not used SSIS for the last few years, so I don't feel competent to compare its latest version with Informatica.

Answer (score 2):

Feature wise they are exactly the same but for some stupid reason the package format has changed and you cannot mix versions.

i.e. Packages created in VS2010/2012 can only be deployed to SQL 2012 instance (SSIS2012 runtime) and VS2013 -> SQL 2014.

If you open a VS2010/2012 solution in VS2013 it will upgrade and you cannot go back.

See this for more feedback.
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/944882/ssdt-bi-2014-backward-compatibility-for-ssis-2012

Edit: it seems you can deploy SSIS2012 packages to SQL2014 using Management Studio as they are automatically upgraded. The rules about Visual Studio still stand.

(I have used this - my team are mixed between 2012 and 2014)

Comment: From what you are saying, it sounds like there is one small change: SSIS 2012 is hosted in VS 2012, but SSIS 2014 is hosted in VS 2013. And perhaps there are zero feature changes in the capabilities of SSIS packages.